# Webrtc React Видеочат, разные браузеры, ошибка

Tags: reactjs, firebase, webrtc

Сделал видео чат на react webrtc firebase. Все работает хорошо. Но когда использую, какой то один браузер, например звоню с chroma на chrome. А вот если начинаю звонить с chroma на firefox ошибка.
Хелп!

Происходит это на ответе.

Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to allocate videosource

```
const pc = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
  console.log('1', pc) //Еще выполняется
  
  const localStream = await window.navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: true,
    // audio: true,
  });
  console.log('2', localStream)  //Уже не выполняется
  const remoteStream = new MediaStream();

  localStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
    pc.addTrack(track, localStream);
  });
```

Comment: Что за ошибка то хоть?

Comment: такое вполне может быть, думаю ошибка у Вас что-то с кодеком `h264` или типа того, в любом случае опишите ее в вопросе, чтобы ответили

Comment: Какое бы решение webrtc не находил. Все работают, только если использоваться один браузер.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решился.
Когда тестируешь все на одном компе с одной камерой возникает, такая вот проблема.
Соединение хрома + хрома работает. Фаер + Хром и др. уже нет.
Когда все выложили, все заработало.
Видимо связано, с потоком с самой камеры.